Ptolemy's theorem for a conic
Any $3$ points (constrained to $2$D without loss of generality) determine a unique inscribed circle, so any $4$th point on that circle is therefore constrained.  This constraint is elegantly stated in one equation with Ptolemy's theorem.
Any $5$ points constrained to $2$D determine a unique inscribed conic (either ellipse, parabola, or hyperbola), so any 6th point on that conic is therefore constrained.  Is there any analog of Ptolemy's theorem for the conic?  If not, what is a simple way of stating the constraints among the $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ point-to-point distances created?
EDIT: I originally used the word "ellipse" instead of "conic" above (4 times), but corrected this per jjagmath's comment.  If, by some miracle, it helps to additionally know the 5 points lie on an ellipse (not a parabola nor a hyperbola), please comment or answer for that case as well.

Any three points (in general position) define a unique plane, so "Any 3 points (constrained to 2D without loss of generality)" is redundant (and needs a "in general position").  "Any 5 points" also needs an "in general position" -- 5 collinear points do not   determine a (non-degenerate) ellipse.

Any 5 points (in general position) determine a unique conic. But that conic may be an ellipse, a parabola or a hyperbola.

Potentially useful: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/OverlookedPascal.shtml
